# Retrieving certificate stored via Safari during enrollment

Tags: ios, objective-c, certificate, keychain, mdm

How can we retrieve identity certificates received from SCEP during enrollment in objective c.

I guess the certificates are stored in KeyChain Access of the device.

PS: I read somewhere that we cannot access other apps keychain via any 3rd party app, so is it possible to get the certificates stored during enrollment process of MDM

Comment: One of the reasons people use SCEP (which is still in draft, by the way), is so they can freely get and register their certificates.  If you're talking about getting the same certificate that you registered from the application that registered it, then sure.  But, if you're trying to use a native application to get a certificate, it isn't possible given both sandboxing and keychain rules

Comment: @CodaFi - Yes, I want to retrieve the same certificate that was installed on the device during enrollment. I want to retrieve the certificate data (Cert and P12) into my native app.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't access it. As you correctly mentioned, it's stored in keychain. And I believe in this case, it will be stored in keychain of Safari or mdmd. And you don't have access to either of those on your device (except, if it's jailbroken).

However, if Certificate authority in your control, potentially you can write server side code which will allow query certificate (not a private key) for your device. Your application will talk to your server and it will go to Certificate authority and get a certificate associated with your device.

Comment: I want to establish secure communication with help of the certificates. So if I want to share Bob's public key with Alice, then how can I ask Alice to generate one from SCEP in favor of Bob and then Alice return it back to Bob?

Comment: You won't be able to establish communications with it. At least one party should have an access to both certificate and key. And none of the parties have the access to private key.